# ViewConfiguration - Setting the zoomControlsTimeout

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to determine how to set the `ViewConfiguration.zoomControlsTimeout` setting in the Android 1.5 framework, when working with a MapView.  There is [information](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#getZoomControlsTimeout()) on how to get this data, but how can I set it?

My end goal is to ensure zoom controls are always displayed on the screen, instead of the default hide/show behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code to `getZoomControlsTimeout()` in `ViewConfiguration` (e.g., use [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/view/ViewConfiguration.java&q=package:android%20ViewConfiguration)), you will see that it is a hardwired constant.

I suspect that you will need to implement your own zoom controls to achieve the look you seek.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I hadn't discovered Google Code Search in my Android work yet!

Comment: Yeah, Google Code Search is a lifesaver for finding stuff in Android. Just put package:android in your search query, and it will restrict your search to Android-related projects (Android itself plus projects in Google Code and github that seem Android-y).